How can I change the color of oiled pine butcher block?
I have applied one coat of food grade mineral oil with vitamin E to my new butcher block counter. I believe it is pine. I do not like the color it turned it. Is it too late to sand & stain it now?

Is the problem that it's too light, or too dark?

It’s yellow pine. So it’s making the yellow stand out. I’d like to make ĩt a little more light brown.

If you're willing to try something different, a tung oil finish will generally turn wood a little more brown.

If you want to go darker and if you are not cutting food directly on the counter, you can sand lightly and stain. (Do not attempt to sand too far. You will get to a point where the oil has penetrated in some spots and not in others. This will make the stain blotchy.)
Apply stain in your prefered color.
Seal with an oil based polyurethane.  Do 4 coats. Lightly sanding in between coats with 400 grit paper and wiping clean, before applying the next coat.

Its never too late. Because the coat you have applied would have soaked in, it may take some effort to sand it enough to remove it.
